# Await for imperative loop call in LWC to complete first

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

Below is the JS file.

```
async tcvChange(event) {
        
        let tempList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lineItems));

        console.log('list before ++'+JSON.stringify(tempList));
        
        await tempList.map(async e => {
            if (e.productId === event.target.name) {
                e.productTerm = event.target.value;

                await getTCV({productTerm: e.productTerm})
                .then(result =>{
                    e.tcv = result;                    
                })

                console.log('tcv ++'+e.tcv);    
            }
        })
        
        console.log('updated list ++'+JSON.stringify(tempList));
        this.lineItems = tempList;
        
    }
```

Console Output -->

```
list before ++
updated list ++
tcv ++
```

Expected Output

```
list before ++
tcv ++
updated list ++
```

Comment: as per my understanding the map await also shall be promise. Then it works smooth.

Comment: Are you calling apex method `getTCV` here? Why not to send the list of `productTerm` and have a single apex call?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should have either `await` or `then..catch`.
2. `await` will wait for the server trip before continuing the main transaction but `then..catch` functions will be passed to async thread for processing later after main transaction is finished.

You need to implement as below:

```js
----- code ---------
        tempList.forEach(async e => {
            if (e.productId === event.target.name) {
                e.productTerm = event.target.value;

                const result = await getTCV({productTerm: e.productTerm});
                e.tcv = result;                    

                console.log('tcv ++'+e.tcv);    
            }
        })
----- code -------
```

However, this is not efficient. I would recommend to bulkify `getTCV` to accept list of product terms - `List<String>`. Since you are also using `event.target.value`, I presume you are invoking this function for some input change. So, I am not sure why you want to change all the lineItems. Anyway, you need to rethink the design for this function to make it efficient.

Comment: I tried implementing above code but it still not working. tcv ++ is coming at end in console logs

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for the issue. Here we need to use Promise.all to get the result from all promises and then proceeds to next statement. :-

```
        const promises = tempList.map(async e => {
            if (e.productId === event.target.name) {
                e.productTerm = event.target.value;

                await getTCV({productTerm: e.productTerm})
                .then(result =>{
                    e.tcv = result;                    
                })

                console.log('tcv ++'+e.tcv);    
            }
        })
        await Promise.all(promises);
        console.log('updated list ++'+JSON.stringify(tempList));
        this.lineItems = tempList;
```